# PHP JSON variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, variables, object

I am generating a JSON "text" using php and want to include that in a javascript in the same file. 
I think I am having problem understanding how java deals with JSON as text vs as an Object.

Note: I am going to change mysql to mysqli soon, just want to get this thing working first.
Here's my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Knox QA tickets status</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="am/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="am/amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<?php
    //$subm = "8";
    // This is being loaded from a selection html script 
    $subm =  $_POST["submoduleID"];
    if(!isset($_POST["submoduleID"]) )
    {
    // set it to the default container if it's not set.
     $subm = "8";
    }

    // Connect to MySQL
    $link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'secret' );
    if ( !$link ) {
      die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
    }

    // Select the data base
    $db = mysql_select_db( 'xqa_status', $link );
    if ( !$db ) {
      die ( 'Error selecting database \'test\' : ' . mysql_error() );
    }

    // Fetch the data
    $query = ("select date, tested, passed from test_status where xqa_id=" . $subm . " order by test_status_id limit 10");

    $result = mysql_query( $query );

    // Make a josn formatted output 
    $rows = array();
    while ( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $chartData_json = json_encode($rows);
    print $chartData_json;
    mysql_close($link);
?>


<!-- Custom Function  
  <script>
    AmCharts.loadJSON = function(file) {
      // create the request
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }

      request.open('GET', file, false);
      request.send();

      // parse adn return the output
      return eval(request.responseText);
    };
  </script> -->


<!-- chart container -->
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>


<!-- the chart code -->
  <script>
    var chart;
    var chartData1 = "<?php echo $chartData_json; ?>";
    var myObject = JSON.parse(chartData1, reviver);
    // create chart
    AmCharts.ready(function() {

      // load the data
      // SERIAL CHART
      chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
      chart.pathToImages = "am/amcharts/images/";
      chart.dataProvider = myObject;
      chart.categoryField = "date";
      chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

      // GRAPHS

      var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph(); 
      graph1.type = "smoothedLine";
      graph1.title = "Tested";
      graph1.valueField = "tested";
      graph1.bullet = "round";
      graph1.bulletSize = 5;
      graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
      graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
      graph1.lineThickness = 2;
      graph1.lineAlpha = 0.5;
      chart.addGraph(graph1);

      var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
      graph2.type = "smoothedLine";
      graph2.title = "Passed";
      graph2.valueField = "passed";
      graph2.bullet = "round";
      graph2.bulletSize = 5;
      graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
      graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
      graph2.lineThickness = 2;
      graph2.lineAlpha = 0.5;
      chart.addGraph(graph2);

      // CATEGORY AXIS
      chart.categoryAxis.parseDates = true;
      chart.categoryAxis.autoGridCount = false;
      chart.categoryAxis.gridCout = chartData.length;
      chart.categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
      chart.categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;

      // LEGEND
      var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
      chart.addLegend(legend);

       // CURSOR
       var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
       chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0;
       chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
       chartCursor.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
       chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

       // SCROLLBAR
       var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
       chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

       // 3D
       // chart.angle = 30;
       // chart.depth3D = 15;



       // WRITE
       chart.write("chartdiv");



    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

A sample of the json output is this:

```
[{"date":"2014-01-09","tested":"12","passed":"32"},{"date":"2014-01-10","tested":"12","passed":"34"},{"date":"2014-01-11","tested":"22","passed":"34"},{"date":"2014-01-12","tested":"22","passed":"34"},{"date":"2014-01-13","tested":"40","passed":"34"},{"date":"2014-01-14","tested":"40","passed":"34"},{"date":"2014-01-15","tested":"40","passed":"34"}]
```

Comment: not very clear.. what is your exact problem?

Comment: mixing javascript and php in one file, oh my

Comment: Thanks Patrick, That did fix my problem, Javascript failed to understand the JSON as an object because it was inside "double quotes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the output of your PHP into a Javascript variable:

```
<script>
  var json_data=<?php

...

?>;

  // Do stuff with json_data
</script>
```

Then `json_data` will be an array or objects in Javascript (it's not JSON anymore since the JSON will be parsed as an array literal, not a string). That is most likely what you want, since then you can work with the array, like `json_data[0].data`.

Comment: don't forget to add quotes around your json. better write something like: var json_data="<?php print $sJSON; ?>";

Comment: @mat, no that would cause errors as json contains quotes in itself, so when javascript loads it it would see sometihng like `"{"somevar":"somevalue"}"` and error out. The way Paulpro has it, the json string will be treated as an object literal.

Comment: But I do have the variable here:
    var chartData1 = "<?php echo $chartData_json; ?>";
The double quotes actually was the problem.

Comment: just use json_encode and json_decode to print json ... it works like a charm with arrays and handles escaping quotes etc...